# Push Items to Salesforce Custom Object via Salesforce Provider in DEF

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I'm having problem to send Sitecore item data to a Salesforce Custom Object.

I am using Sitecore 9.1.1 and DEF 2.1.0 and the Salesforce Provider. I used these following pipeline steps to send Sitecore item data to Salesforce. I was successful in pulling Salesforce data to create Sitecore items.

[image]

Please confirm are these steps correct for this operation? Please suggest.

Comment: The pipelines seems ok. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Sitecore Item not getting created in the Object in Salesforce. Inspite of giving the field name and correct object name in Add Salesforce Object pipeline step and Resolve pipeline step and in Submit Items Queue pipeline step.

Comment: Can you please share some more details how you have created this pipelines and everything,i have similar requirement and needs to push data from Sitecore to CRM.